# Using PostGIS for location based data

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.0

I have a table in postgresql 9.2 that stores the latitude and longitude of locations as integer values.

I intend to do something like when a user searches for a location, he also gets information on other locations that are within a 7 mile radius of that searched location.

How do i use postGIS for this since i am new to it. Any idea.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll actually want to store the latitude and longitude as a point.

```
CREATE TABLE postal_codes
(
  zip character varying(7) NOT NULL,
  state character(2) NOT NULL,
  city character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  geoloc geography(Point,4326) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO postal_codes
VALUES (
    '35004', 'AL', 'Moody',
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-86.50249 33.606379)') -- lon lat
);
```

You can then get all points within a certain distance using [STDWithin](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_DWithin.html).

```
SELECT geoloc
FROM postal_codes
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    geoloc,                            -- The current point being evaluated
    'thegeolocyoustoredawaysomewhere', -- the location of the person
                                       -- you're giving info to
    7 * 1.6 * 1000                     -- Miles to meters
);
```

Or:

```
SELECT geoloc
FROM postal_codes
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    geoloc,
    (
        SELECT geoloc
        FROM postal_codes
        WHERE zip = '12345'
    ),
    7 * 1.6 * 1000
);
```

To boost performance a bit for other kinds of queries (not any seen here), use a GiST index:

```
CREATE INDEX geoloc_idx
ON postal_codes
USING gist (geoloc);
```

Comment: What about performance? I assume the user Neville is storing lat/lng as integers to increase performance (maybe because of using modest hardware)

Comment: On my Pentium II 233 MHz server (that's right, server) a similar query will take about 30 seconds to complete. About 5 seconds on my modern workstation.

Comment: That is just the point. I am serving the site www.mapatia.com with an Atom N550. This server has a few millions of geopoints stored on a Postgresql table and I also manage lat/lng as integers just to get faster index operations. I need response times in the range of 100 ms or faster.

Comment: You can generate a 3 column table (geo1, geo2, distance) to cache that kind of data to get sub-100 ms rather than doing the same calculation repeatedly. Or, parital indexes (USING gist (ST_DWithin(geo1, geo2, distance))), or partition your tables.